# Erlang/OTP upgrade lose existing RabbitMQ messages

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, upgrade, erlang-otp

I had `Erlang/OTP 17` and `RabbitMQ Server 3.4.3` installed on my local windows box. Before upgrading to the newer versions in production, I wanted to give it a try on my local box to see if upgrade won't cause any problem. I am trying to upgrade them to the latest versions - `Erlang/OTP 21` and `RabbitMQ Server 3.7.8`. When I do upgrade, I lost all my existing messages.

I had some existing messages in multiple queues. As soon as I upgraded Erlang/OTP (21), I see all my existing messages are gone. I even tried installing the newer RabbitMQ Server (3.7.8), still I don't see my old messages in the queues. I thought `mnesia` database would help in restoring the messages. I guess either I don't understand the concept or I am missing some settings.

I don't want our production clients complain about the messages being lost. I couldn't find much help online on this topic. But, surely RabbitMQ documentation talks about `Blue-Green Deployment Strategy`, never did that, so was not sure if that would help in our case, or it is an overkill and has a simpler solution. Also, want to add that I did all manual upgrade. If anyone know a better process of upgrade for single node without losing the existing messages, please guide and help me.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation clearly states that you can't upgrade directly from version `3.4.3` to version `3.7.8`: [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/upgrade.html). You must first upgrade to `3.6.16`.

In your case, using a [blue-green upgrade](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blue-green-upgrade.html) would be the only way to avoid having to first upgrade to version `3.6.16` prior to `3.7.8`.